# Count the duplicates in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples: `a = [(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(6,7),(2,9)]` I want to check if one of the individual elements of each tuple matches the same position/element in another tuple, and how many times this occurs.

For example: If only the 1st element in some tuples has a duplicate, return the tuple and how many times it's duplicated.
I can do that with the following code:

```
a = [(1,2), (1,4), (1,2), (6,7), (2,9)]

coll_list = []
for t in a:
    coll_cnt = 0
    for b in a:
        if b[0] == t[0]:
            coll_cnt = coll_cnt + 1
    print "%s,%d" %(t,coll_cnt)
    coll_list.append((t,coll_cnt))

print coll_list
```

I want to know if there is a more effective way to do this?

Comment: `collections.Counter(a)` will give you the counts.

Comment: If your code is working, but you want to improve it, you could post it here: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might want to show expected output, since a lot of the answers below seem to be about finding duplicate tuples and not duplicate values within the tuples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use collections library. In the following code val_1, val_2 give you duplicates of each first elements and second elements of the tuples respectively.

```
import collections
val_1=collections.Counter([x for (x,y) in a])
val_2=collections.Counter([y for (x,y) in a])

>>> print val_1
<<< Counter({1: 3, 2: 1, 6: 1})
```

This is the number of occurrences of the first element of each tuple

```
>>> print val_2
<<< Counter({2: 2, 9: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1})
```

This is the number of occurrences of the second element of each tuple

Answer (score 13):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
a = [(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(6,7),(2,9)]
counter=Counter(a)
print counter
```

This will output:

```
Counter({(1, 2): 2, (6, 7): 1, (2, 9): 1, (1, 4): 1})
```

It is a dictionary like object with the item (tuples in this case) as the key and a value containing the number of times that key was seen. Your `(1,2)` tuple is seen twice, while all others are only seen once.

```
>>> counter[(1,2)]
2
```

---

If you are interested in each individual portion of the tuple, you can utilize the same logic for each element in the tuple.

```
first_element = Counter([x for (x,y) in a])
second_element = Counter([y for (x,y) in a])
```

`first_element` and `second_element` now contain a `Counter` of the number of times values are seen *per element* in the tuple

```
>>> first_element
Counter({1: 3, 2: 1, 6: 1})
>>> second_element
Counter({2: 2, 9: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1})
```

Again, these are dictionary like objects, so you can check how frequent a specific value appeared directly:

```
>>> first_element[2]
1
```

In the first element of your list of tuples, the value `2` appeared 1 time.

Comment: The OP didn't want the number of occurrences of each tuple.

Answer (score 4):

You can make count_map, and store the count of each tuple as the value.

```
>>> count_map = {}
>>> for t in a:
...     count_map[t] = count_map.get(t, 0)  +1
... 
>>> count_map
{(1, 2): 2, (6, 7): 1, (2, 9): 1, (1, 4): 1}
```

Comment: You can also use `collections.defaultdict(int)` to avoid the awkward `get`.

Comment: The OP didn't want the number of occurrences of each tuple.

Comment: @doru OP's code says otherwise. He/she has calculated counts of all tuples one by one, making it a N^2 operation.

Comment: @Sudipta have you run the OP code to see the what are the desired results?

Comment: @doru- Yes I have done that. OP code is for checking `if only the 1st part of all tuples of the list has a dublicate`. But now OP needs a code to find: `if one of the elements of each tuple has a dublicate and how many times`.

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas this is simple and very fast:

```
import pandas
print(pandas.Series(data=[(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(6,7),(2,9)]).value_counts())

(1, 2)    2
(1, 4)    1
(6, 7)    1
(2, 9)    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The OP didn't want the number of occurrences of each tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Dictionary can work better. Because in your code, you are traveling the list for twice. And this makes the [complexity](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) of your code O(n^2). And this is not a good thing :)

Best way is the travelling for once and to use 1 or 2 conditions for each traverse. Here is the my first solution for such kind of problem.

```
a = [(1,2),(1,4),(1,2),(6,7),(2,9)]

dict = {}
for (i,j) in a:
    if dict.has_key(i):
            dict[i] += 1
    else:
            dict[i] = 1

print dict
```

For this code, this will give the output:

```
{1: 3, 2: 1, 6: 1}
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: You can use `collections.defaultdict(int)` to clean up the inside of the loop a bit

Comment: Yeah, that would clear. But if I use collections, why try to make a loop, right? :) I'd prefer a solution like Andy's one ;)