# How to check height and width of drawn rectangle PYTHON

Tags: python

I am a student just beginning with Python and I am using JES. What my program does is draw the given amount of rectangles in the parameter with a random random height and width within the given parameter "maxSize", everything is working smoothly however I am trying to check the amount of squares drawn, how can I check to see if the height and width are the same? Should I have used range to create a list instead of using randint? Very confused how I can go about checking the width and height and storing each number in a variable to see if they equal eachother. Sorry if I sound unclear.

```html
def partB(width,height,numRectangle,maxSize):
    pic = makeEmptyPicture(width,height,black)  
    drawn = 0
    numSquares = 0  
    while drawn < numRectangle:
        from random import randint
        import random
        randomX = randint(0,width)
        randomY = randint(0,height)
        randomSize = randint (0,maxSize)
        widthRect = randomSize
        heightRect = randomSize 
        addRectFilled(pic,randomX,randomY,widthRect,heightRect,red)
        if widthRect == heightRect:
            numSquares+=1
        drawn+=1
    show (pic)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the number of differently (or identically) sized rectangles? 
You could e.g. create a list of random width and height tuples and then count the number of uniques, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207717/1647737

To help with counting, split your code in two functions, one to generate the list of random rectangles (tuples) and another to draw a given list of rectangles (tuples). This way, you clearly separate two concerns; you separate the model of your rectangles (list of tuples) from their rendering on screen, also called view.

Comment: I want to check if width and height are the same for the drawn rectangles then add it to the total. After checking out that post you linked that looks like it will solve my question. But there must be a more simpler way, without using the function counter. Thanks for the quick helpful response, will be trying it tomorrow.