# Most efficient way to count duplicate tuples in python list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list with more than 100 millions of tuples, with key-value elements like this:

```
list_a = [(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (1,'a'), (3,'b'), (3,'b'), (1,'a')]
```

I need to output a second list like this:

```
list_b = [(1,'a', 3), (2, 'b', 1), (3, 'b', 2) ]
```

Last element in a tuple is the count of duplicates in the list for such tuple. Order in list_b doesn't matter.

Then, I wrote this code:

```
import collections

list_b = []

for e, c in collections.Counter(list_a).most_common():
    list_b.append("{}, {}, {}".format(e[0], e[1], c))
```

Running with 1000 tuples it last 2 seconds approximately... figure out how long will take with more that 100 millions. Any idea to speed it up?

Comment: `collections.Counter()` is a very good tool for this.  You could speed it up by skipping the string formatting in the `for` loop and form 3-tuples directly.

Comment: @AbbeGijly yes, You're right, but do you think it will be a significant improvement? I mean after creation of the list I will need to format it anyway.

Comment: You could also replace `.most_common()` with `.items()`.  That will skip an unnecessary sort operation on the list.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207601/count-the-duplicates-in-a-list-of-tuples You will get some idea.

Comment: @AbbeGijly good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Your bottle neck is using `list.append` method, since it's running on native python instead of the innate C code, it'll perform much slower.

You can opt to use list comprehension instead and it'll be much faster:

```
c = Counter(list_a)
result = [(*k, v) for k, v in c.items()]
```

Ran this on a 1000 item list on my machine, it was pretty quick.

Comment: It looks reasonable your point. I've tested with 100.000 tuples and your idea reduce a 27% of running time. I'm going to try with a more huge number and then will let you know.

Comment: After a benchmark items() is faster a 24%. Avoiding append() reduce almost a 8%.  Eliminating format() reduce only 3%.